# Mongoose saving empty record despite schema "require"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, model

I'm creating a Node.js app that uses Mongoose and Express to create a RESTful API.  The Mongoose schema defines required fields; however, when I submit an empty POST via Postman, the API creates empty records.  Why isn't Mongoose / MongoDB preventing a save based on my schema?

I'm just learning node.js / express / mongoose / mongodb and coming from a mySQL/MSSQL world so I may be thinking about schema required fields the wrong way (i.e. like a database constraint)

**Here is my router:**

```
// Initialize controller(s) for CRUD
var customer = require('../controllers/customercontroller');

// Initialize Router
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/:id', function (req, res) {
    console.log("Customer Requested");

    customer.read(req, res);
});

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log("Customer List Requested");
    customer.getList(req, res);
});

router.put("/:id", function (req, res) {
    console.log("Updating Customer");
    customer.update(req, res);

});

router.post("/", function (req, res) {
    console.log("Creating Customer");
    customer.create(req, res);

});

router.delete("/:id", function (req, res) {
    console.log("Delete Customer");
    customer.delete(req, res);
});

module.exports = router;
```

**Here is my controller:**

```
var Customer = require('../models/customermodel');

exports.getList = function (req, res) {
    Customer.find({}, function (err, customer) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
        res.json(customer);
    });
};

exports.create = function (req, res) {
    var customer = new Customer(req.body);
    customer.save(function (err, customer) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
        res.json(customer);
    });
};

exports.read = function (req, res) {
    Customer.find(req.params.id, function (err, customer) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
        res.json(customer);
    });
};

exports.update = function (req, res) {
    Customer.findOneAndUpdate(req.params.id, function (err, customer) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
        res.json(customer);
    });
};

exports.delete = function (req, res) {
    Customer.remove({_id: req.params.id}, function (err, customer) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
        res.json({ message: 'Customer deleted'});
    });
};
```

**And here is my model:**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/hs_db');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var CustomerSchema = new Schema({
    "name": { type: String, Required: 'Required: name' },
    "alias": { type: String, Required: 'Required: alias' },
    "email": { type: String, Required: 'Required: email' },
    "address1": { type: String, Required: 'Required: address1' },
    "address2": { type: String, Required: 'Required: address2' },
    "address3": { type: String, Required: 'Required: address3' },
    "city": { type: String, Required: 'Required: city' },
    "state": { type: String, Required: 'Required: state' },
    "postcode": { type: String, Required: 'Required: postcode' },
    "country": { type: String, Required: 'Required: country' },
    "created": { type: Date, Required: 'Required: date' },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('customer', CustomerSchema);
```

**When I post an empty body** with Postman and query the result with the mongo console:

```
> db.customers.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("591f25ae0cca8f5148cce551"), "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("591f25d40cca8f5148cce552"), "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("591f25f00cca8f5148cce553"), "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("591f2764dc5a191fe8730ccd"), "__v" : 0 }
>
```

**SO, my question:**

Isn't the schema supposed to validate the data and prevent the save similar to a database constraint in mySQL or MSSQL?  Or does the schema just give data for a node.js controller to reference, requiring me to create business logic to enforce the constraint?

Comment: Arghh.....that was it!  Stupid programmer error :)  Thanks for the fresh set of eyes!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The schema property names are case sensitive, so change your `Required` fields to `required`:

```
var CustomerSchema = new Schema({
    "name": { type: String, required: 'Required: name' },
    "alias": { type: String, required: 'Required: alias' },
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

In a simple way, you can define required field as below:

```
var CustomerSchema = new Schema({
    "name": { type: String, required: true },
    "alias": { type: String, required: true },
    ...
```